# UIAttachement behavior to make 2 views act like one view when dragging around

Tags: ios, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I have a little view that I would like to attach to a bigger view.
When either of the views is dragged on the x axis I would like the other to move accordingly - as if they were one awkward shaped view

I tried

```
UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

UIAttachmentBehavior *attach = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:firstItem attachedToSecondItem:secondItem];

[animator addBehavior:attach];
```

but they aren't moving like one big view :(

Comment: Why don't you add the little view as a subview of the big view? They will appear attached and the big view will obviously drag the small view.

Comment: They don't belong to each other - one is in a table view - the other is a random view

Comment: So what? They are both subclasses of UIView are they not?

Comment: That makes no sense -maybe my question is unclear - one item is a tableview cell - i want when it is dragged - that it will drag a different view in a different heirarchy